# Why my JDBC call is consuming memory 4 times more that actual size of data

Tags: java, jdbc

I wrote a small java program which loads data from DB2 database using simple JDBC call. I am using select query to get data and using java statement for this purpose. I have properly closed statement and connection objects. I am using 64 bit JVM for compilation and for running the program.

The query is returning 52 million records, each row having 24 columns, which takes me around 4 minutes to load complete data in Unix (having multiprocessor environment). I am using HashMap as data-structure to load the data: `Map<String, Map<String, GridTradeStatus>>`. The bean **GridTradeStatus** is a simple getter/setter bean with 24 properties in it.

The memory required for the program is alarmingly high. Java heap size goes up to 5.8 - 6GB to load complete data while actual used heap size remains between 4.7 - 4.9GB. I know that we should not load this much data into memory but my business requirements are in that way only.

The question is that when I put whole data of my table in a flat file it comes out to be roughly equivalent to ~1.2GB. I want to know why my java program is consuming memory 4 times more that its actual size.

Comment: Strings in java uses UTF-16, which mean 2 bytes for each char. So that causes duple the ram usage there if your txt file is a normal 8bit/char encoding. Also If you use the substring method, remember that the original string newer is freed, as long as the substring object is alive.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Is it somehow possible to direct JVM to use UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: Not directly. java.lang.String will always use UTF-16. But I am sure that a google search can give you a java string class, which uses utf-8 or an other 8bit encoding.

Comment: Yes it was helpful many thanks, after searching for some time I found a vmoption `-XX:+UseCompressedStrings` here (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) which signals use of byte[] in String. By using this option I can see memory improvement of around ~500MB.

Comment: The real question here is why you are loading 52 million rows into memory. This is poor practice and given data growth, sooner or later it will cease to work at all. Process them a row at a time.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing surprising here (to me at least).

a.) Strings in java consume double the space compared to most common text formats (because Strings are always represented as UTF-16 in the heap). Also, String as an object has quite some overhead (String object itself, reference to the char[] it contains, hashCode etc.). For small strings the String object costs easily as much memory as the data it contains.

b.) You put stuff into a HashMap. HashMap is not exactly memory efficient. First it uses a default load factor of 75%, which means a map with many entries has also a big bucket array. Then, each entry in the map is an object itself, which costs at least two references (key and value) plus object overhead.

In conclusion you pretty much have to *expect* the memory requirements to increase quite a bit. A factor of 4 is reasonable if your average data String is relatively short.

Answer (score 0):

If you think you cannot afford a ratio 1:4 between the size of data in a flat file and the memory  necessary to load the Strings in a HashMap, you should considere not using Java but a lower level language such as C++ or even C.

Of course there are possible optimizations :

- use `byte[]` instead of `String` (about half the size)
- do not use default `HashMap` parameters (initial size / load factor) but tweak them to meet your actual requirements.

What follows is mainly <del>experience</del> opinion based. I generally use 4 language levels :

- high level scripting language (Python, Ruby, or even bash ...) when performance
  is not a requirement and speed of developpement is
- mid level language (Java, less frequently high level C++) when performance matters but when I also want simplicity of developpement and robustness (strong typing, ...)
- low level language (low level C++, or C) what performance is a high requirement and when I accept to spend much more time in writing and testing individual modules
- assembly language for the small parts where performance **is** critical and has been proved to be by profiling.

IMHO you can tweak Java code to highly reduce the memory footprint, but you risk to lose a great part of the interest of Java by losing the excellent string and collections support. It might be as easy and perhaps more efficient to code a small part of the application in C++ and use JNI to tie all together.